# UrlFetchApp versus a webapp in Google appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function in a sheet script

```
function callwebapp() {
UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://script.google.com/a/macros/customer_name.com/s/xxxxxxxxxx2zEvlMg1T4h6lljoulNrJjGgS5q2T7ukl65tZQ3wY-Zxxv_MYzd-/exec");
}
```

which is calling the link at which a webapp should respond and execute some code.
If I manually launch the link in a browser, it works, but if I execute the "obtain" function..it doesn't.
Any idea?
thank you

Comment: What is being returned?

Comment: try Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url));

Comment: How is the web app deployed? Can you provide the both scripts to try to reproduce it? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I did a similiar thing from an gmail add-on as follows:

```
function deleteBlackList() {
  const url=Utilities.formatString('%s?mode=dable',burl());//burl is just a function that returns a web app url
  const params={"muteHttpExceptions":true,"method":"get","headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer " +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  const resp=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);
  const ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "Some/where", "E MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  Logger.log(url);
  Logger.log(resp.getContentText("UTF-8"));
  var action=CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('buildEmailFilterUI');  
  return CardService.newCardBuilder()
  .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('Deleted BlackListed Emails')).addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
  .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText(Utilities.formatString('TimeStamp: %s\n%s\n',ts,resp.getContentText()))))
  .addSection(CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(CardService.newTextButton().setText('Return to Opening Form').setOnClickAction(action)))
  .build();
}
```

It works just fine

Comment: Logging the response I understand I am not authorized...
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
is a problem with the options used to deploy the webapp?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got teh problem is in the authorization. I had to show the manifest file on the script calling the url of the web app.
I then added in the json

```
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
  ]
```

and it started working.
thank you